# How can I use different markup with kss-node generated html?

Tags: html, css, dynamically-generated, knyle-style-sheet

I'm grunting up a styleguide using kss-node but I want to use different markup for different section pages (i.e. different modifiers), how can I accomplish this?

My index.html template does this:

```
  {{#eachSection rootName}}
    {{#ifDepth 1}}
      <!-- Do the things. -->
    {{else}}
      <!-- Don't. -->
    {{/ifDepth}}
    {{#if markup}}
      {{#if description}}
        <!-- Description. -->
      {{/if}}

      <div class="kss-example">{{{markup}}}</div>
      <!--<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">{{markup}}</pre>-->

    {{#eachModifier}}
      <!-- MY CSS EXAMPLES -->
    {{/eachModifier}}

     <hr />

    {{else}}
      {{#if description}}
        <!-- Whatever. -->
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
    </section>
  {{/eachSection}}
```

How do I get a section page to use this:

```
  {{#eachModifier}}
    <!-- MY ICON IMAGES -->
  {{/eachModifier}}
```

Instead of this:

```
  {{#eachModifier}}
    <!-- MY CSS EXAMPLES -->
  {{/eachModifier}}
```

I tried stuff like the below code with a conditional 'if' helper for handlebars, but no luck:

```
  {{#iff header '==' "Icons"}}
    {{#eachModifier}}
      <!-- MY ICON IMAGES -->
    {{/eachModifier}}
  {{/iff}}

  {{else}}
    {{#eachModifier}}
      <!-- MY CSS EXAMPLES -->
    {{/eachModifier}}
```

My KSS looks like this: (obviously the Icons one is different)

```
/*
Example CSS

Example css file with KSS for style guide.

Markup:
<h1 class="{{modifier_class}}">Example Text</h1>

.example-grey - Grey
.example-green - Green
.example-brown - Brown
.example-yellow - Yellow

Styleguide 1.1
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah. Turns out I needed to simply edit the line under "Markup:" in my CSS file. I was going a level too low and attempting to edit the actual framework!